# Angularjs on https and http

Tags: apache, angularjs, .htaccess

I tried different ways to make only the login page to server on https and the rest of the app with http but no success.

Version: 1.2.14
Web Server: Apache 2.2

I have tried the following:

1. Remove the # and make it pretty url but this didn't work. Tried adding locationprovider html5 enable to true and added rewrite rules in .htaccess
2. Tried different rewritecond and rewriterule in apache to identify the login pattern and redirect to https but no luck

> ```
> RewriteEngine On  
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
> RewriteRule ^(/?login/)$ https://www.domain.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
> ```

Note: My login url starts as follows:

http://www.domain.com/#/login/

Thanks

Comment: any help from anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Enable

```
locationProvider.HTML5mode(true);
```

Put this to the top of your index.html file:

```
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
 <base href="http://www.domain/#/" />
```

Add this to your `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /Projects/www
# Don't rewrite files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

Comment: This doesn't help for my scenario where I want some set of pages in https and the rest on http.